# If No Value is given to field, this total <tr> should hide

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to alter a table in wordpress template.

```
<tr>
  <td><?php the_field('flipkart_price'); ?></td>
</tr>
```

If No Value is given to `flipkart_price` , this total `tr` should hide. 
Need a small php line for this.

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. We're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to write code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and the community will catch up on your question and help you to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for get field

```
<?php if( get_field('flipkart_price') ): ?>
    <tr><td><?php the_field('flipkart_price'); ?></td></tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```